# Why isn't text alignment animated in this HTML?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Why isn't the text align changed? Here's my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS 3 Animation</title>
<style>
.table
{
width: 400px;
height: 80px;
border: 1px dotted black;
}

.animatedMargin
{
font-size: xx-large;
-webkit-animation: marginAnimation 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marginAnimation
{
from   {text-align: left}
to     {text-align: right}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td class="animatedMargin">
SAMPLE TEXT
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've changed `text-align` to `background` to see if it works, and it did. So is it something with `text-align`?

Comment: You could get a similar effect using padding left instead -> http://jsfiddle.net/6wnKv/1/

Comment: @JustinBicknell I do know that content offset is a way to do so, just wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text-align is not supposed to be [a transitionable property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css).

Answer (score 0):

I think **text-align** simply can not be animated.

Answer (score 0):

- Exactly text-align is not supposed to be a [transitionable property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css).